# Authentication with password in MongoDB 5.0

Tags: mongodb

Authentication with password in MongoDB 5.0 
I would like to put a password to enter and protect my databases from the rest of the
users in MongoDB. I need to do it on MongoDB 5.0 version
Could someone help me, thanks in advance.

Here my image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the [official docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/) well explained...

General steps are as follow:

1.Start MongoDB without authentication. ...

2.Connect to the server using the mongo shell. ...

3.Create the user administrator. ...

4.Enable authentication in mongod configuration file. ...

5.Connect and authenticate as the user administrator. ...

6.Finally, create additional users as needed.